# android studio - take out styles from installed app in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

something bad is happened to my computer and and I lost a project's res folder, I was working on it for about 1 week

the only thing I need now is the res directory, I've connected my phone to pc and I tested the app on my phone , the app is installed on the phone

I was wondering if there is a way to take out the res folder from my phone , or from generated build files in my directory or any other way to restore it

could any one help me ? is there any way or suggestion ?

---EDIT
I need layouts file mostly

Comment: You can analyze your apk in android studio and get your assets/res folder

Comment: @AnasMehar thanks for reply , could you tell me how can I do so ?

Comment: I need layouts mostly ,is it possible ?

Comment: This isn't going to help you now, but things like this is why version control is important. Consider using Git, subversion, or any other VCS with your project to make it possible to recover previous versions of files if anything like this happens in the future

Comment: Yes it's possible you can go to android studio build option and then select analyze apk and select your apk.